# Django: queryset filter for *all* values from a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Hi (sorry for my bad english :p)

Imagine these models :

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    # ...

class Basket(models.Model):
    fruits = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit)
```

Now I would like to retrieve Basket instances related to *all* fruits.
The problem is that the code bellow returns Basket instances related to *any* fruits :

```
baskets = Basket.objects.filter(fruits__in=Fruit.objects.all())

# This doesn't work:
baskets = Basket.objects.filter(fruits=Fruit.objects.all())
```

Any solution do resolve this problem ?

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a dataset handy to test this, but I think it should work:

```
Basket.objects.annotate(num_fruits=Count('fruits')).filter(num_fruits=len(Fruit.objects.all()))
```

It annotates every basket object with the count of related fruits and filters out those baskets that have a fruit count that equals the total amount of fruits.

Note: you need Django 1.1 for this to work.